# Многопоточное выполнение операций JButton

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Скажите пожалуйста, в приведенном ниже коде не возможно запустить выполнение второго потока, пока не будет завершен первый, подскажите как можно доработать код, что бы можно было запускать два потока одновременно?

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        JButton button1=new JButton("Поток 1");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i=0;i<200000;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Поток-1 - "+i);
                }

            }});
        JButton button2=new JButton("Поток 2");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i=0;i<200000;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Поток-2 - "+i);
                }

            }});
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
}
```

Comment: В приведённом коде вообще нет многопоточности. От первой до последней строки выполняется только один поток.

Comment: В том и вопрос, как сделать многопоточной выполнение?

Comment: Для начала надо добавить потоки и определиться, что и почему должно в отдельных потоках работать.

Comment: В разных потоках должны работать нажатия кнопок.

Comment: @Александр [так](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Содержимое метода actionPerformed() для button1 перенесите в первый поток, и вместо него вызывайте thread1.start(). Ну и то же для button2